# Can't push to git through SCM Manager

Tags: git, smart-http, scmmanager

I've got Git running on a Windows server, and want to sync back to it from my OSX laptop. There seems to be two viable options for this:

- SSH (which seems to be hackish at best for Windows)
- Smart HTTP

I've opted for the Smart HTTP option and set up https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home. This seems to tick all the boxes I need, with the exception of actually working.

I can easily clone and pull a repository, but can't push. I've tried it with port forwards etc, but in favour of eliminating as many variables as possible I'm currently testing via a VPN.

```
..$ git clone http://user@192.168.12.201:8080/scm/git/foo
Cloning into 'foo'...
Password: 
remote: Counting objects: 79, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (79/79)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (60/60)
remote: Compressing objects:  96% (58/60)
Unpacking objects: 100% (79/79), done.
remote: Total 79 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0)

..$ cd foo/

..$ touch blah

..$ git add blah

..$ git commit -m 'Testing this works'
[master 1c1637c] Testing this works
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 blah

..$ git push
Password: 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 281 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: [SCM] 
remote:  ! [rejected] refs/heads/master (unspecified reason)
```

And the file isn't turning up in the remote repository.

Any ideas what's going on? Any better method I could be using to remotely sync?

edit:

```
..$ git push -v
Pushing to http://user@192.168.12.201:8080/scm/git/foo
Password: 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 281 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: [SCM] 
remote:  ! [rejected] refs/heads/master (unspecified reason)
```

edit 2 - the logs from SCM:

```
20:22:29.997 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.boot.BootstrapListener - start scm-manager 1.24 in stage: PRODUCTION
20:22:30.001 [Thread-0] WARN  sonia.scm.boot.BootstrapListener - fallback to default classloader
20:22:30.018 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.plugin.DefaultPluginLoader - load core plugin /C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-scm-webapp.war-_scm-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/scm-git-plugin-1.24.jar
20:22:30.257 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.plugin.DefaultPluginLoader - load core plugin /C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-scm-webapp.war-_scm-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/scm-hg-plugin-1.24.jar
20:22:30.261 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.plugin.DefaultPluginLoader - load core plugin /C:/Windows/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-scm-webapp.war-_scm-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/scm-svn-plugin-1.24.jar
20:22:30.407 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - add GuiceModule sonia.scm.web.SvnServletModule
20:22:30.408 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - add GuiceModule sonia.scm.web.HgServletModule
20:22:30.408 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - add GuiceModule sonia.scm.web.GitServletModule
20:22:30.620 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.util.ScmConfigurationUtil - load ScmConfiguration from file C:\.scm\config\config.xml
20:22:30.864 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.event.ScmEventBus - use sonia.scm.event.GuavaScmEventBus as event bus implementation
20:22:30.890 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryHandler sonia.scm.repository.HgRepositoryHandler
20:22:30.891 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryServiceResolver sonia.scm.repository.spi.GitRepositoryServiceResolver
20:22:30.891 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryServiceResolver sonia.scm.repository.spi.HgRepositoryServiceResolver
20:22:30.892 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryHandler sonia.scm.repository.SvnRepositoryHandler
20:22:30.892 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryHandler sonia.scm.repository.GitRepositoryHandler
20:22:30.892 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.BindingExtensionProcessor - bind RepositoryServiceResolver sonia.scm.repository.spi.SvnRepositoryServiceResolver
20:22:30.927 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.ScmServletModule - configure jersey with package path: sonia.scm
20:22:31.829 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager - added RepositoryHandler class sonia.scm.repository.HgRepositoryHandler for type Type{name=hg, displayName=Mercurial}
20:22:31.838 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager - added RepositoryHandler class sonia.scm.repository.SvnRepositoryHandler for type Type{name=svn, displayName=Subversion}
20:22:31.839 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager - added RepositoryHandler class sonia.scm.repository.GitRepositoryHandler for type Type{name=git, displayName=Git}
20:22:31.844 [Thread-0] WARN  sonia.scm.cache.EhCacheManager - could not find cache sonia.cache.authorizing, create new from defaults
20:22:31.893 [Thread-0] INFO  sonia.scm.boot.BootstrapFilter - fallback to default classloader for GuiceFilter
20:22:37.701 [qtp1749190291-19] ERROR sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook - could not handle receive commands
sonia.scm.repository.RepositoryNotFoundException: null
    at sonia.scm.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.fireHookEvent(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:277) ~[classes/:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook.handleReceiveCommands(GitReceiveHook.java:282) [scm-git-plugin-1.24.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook.onReceive(GitReceiveHook.java:338) [scm-git-plugin-1.24.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook.onPreReceive(GitReceiveHook.java:137) [scm-git-plugin-1.24.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.service(ReceivePack.java:203) [org.eclipse.jgit-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.receive(ReceivePack.java:160) [org.eclipse.jgit-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.ReceivePackServlet.doPost(ReceivePackServlet.java:187) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.UrlPipeline$Chain.doFilter(UrlPipeline.java:237) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.ReceivePackServlet$Factory.doFilter(ReceivePackServlet.java:144) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.UrlPipeline$Chain.doFilter(UrlPipeline.java:235) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.RepositoryFilter.doFilter(RepositoryFilter.java:151) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.UrlPipeline$Chain.doFilter(UrlPipeline.java:235) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:80) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.UrlPipeline$Chain.doFilter(UrlPipeline.java:235) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.UrlPipeline.service(UrlPipeline.java:215) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.SuffixPipeline.service(SuffixPipeline.java:101) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.MetaFilter.doFilter(MetaFilter.java:175) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.glue.MetaServlet.service(MetaServlet.java:133) [org.eclipse.jgit.http.server-2.1.0.201209190230-r.jar:2.1.0.201209190230-r]
    at sonia.scm.web.ScmGitServlet.service(ScmGitServlet.java:134) [scm-git-plugin-1.24.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.filter.PermissionFilter.doFilter(PermissionFilter.java:170) [scm-core-1.24.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.24.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.filter.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:186) [scm-core-1.24.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.24.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.filter.BaseUrlFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlFilter.java:100) [classes/:na]
    at sonia.scm.web.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:102) [scm-core-1.24.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at sonia.scm.boot.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:104) [classes/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1300) [jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:445) [jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:556) [jetty-security-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1038) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:374) [jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:972) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:931) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:992) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856) [jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240) [jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628) [jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) [jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_10]
20:22:37.707 [qtp1749190291-19] WARN  sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook - abort git push request with msg: null
```

I noticed this bit halfway down with an error:

```
20:22:37.701 [qtp1749190291-19] ERROR sonia.scm.web.GitReceiveHook - could not handle receive commands
```

Comment: Can you run with `git push -v` to get some more verbose logs?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu Have edit my OP - doesn't reveal anything more.

Comment: What does the Apache log contain/reveal on the server side? My https config works well (even though it calls `gitolite` first, before `git-http-backend`): https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L132

Comment: @VonC No Apache - SCM Manager does everything out-of-the-box. Can always install Apache on the server and try a different web interface. Logs from SCM are in the OP.

Comment: @SpoonNZ any possibility to access those logs? Or to see if *any* logs has just been modified after one failed push? That would help debugging the error.

Comment: @SpoonNZ hmmm... this comes from https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/src/9efc268ce034711574864aaa79b653e997109550/scm-plugins/scm-git-plugin/src/main/java/sonia/scm/web/GitReceiveHook.java?at=default#cl-268: handleReceiveCommands Is it possible you didn't create a bare repo on the server first? (Or make SCM Maanger create one?)

Comment: It's possible I created the repo incorrectly. It does work fine over a network file share. I'll create a new repo through SCM and see what happens.

Comment: Getting closer. Created a new repo from SCM. Works fine - the difference is that yes, the one from SCM is a bare repo. I don't want a bare one though. I want actual files and things. Wrong tool for the job perhaps?

Comment: No,no: bare repo is fine. You should push to a bare repo. I expect SCM Manager to manager bare repo. You can add an hook to clone/checkout that bare repo in the location of your choice on the server. A bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117812/view-website-live-after-git-push?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging

Comment: Note the error was from https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/src/9efc268ce034/scm-webapp/src/main/java/sonia/scm/repository/DefaultRepositoryManager.java?at=default#cl-261

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into rejigging the setup to get it right!

Comment: You could enable trace logging of scm-manager, to get more informations. https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/faq ... section "How do i enable trace logging".

Comment: Any luck with that "rejigging"?

Comment: Yes! I've ended up changing quite a few things. I'm now using bare repositories, with post-receive hooks to move the files to a third folder. I've also removed SCM-Manager and am using Git's built in smart http stuff so the hooks work right. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should retry with the latest version of the SCM-Manager from https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/download. There where much development in the last months. Check your configuration and increment the logging level to TRACE. Maybe there is an encoding problem between your windows server and mac client. You should also consult the mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/scmmanager to get help directly from the developer.

Comment: Thanks - I've figured out an alternate method now which seems to be working pretty well. Subscribing to the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" theory now.